# Error : strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int

Tags: python, django, time

I am trying to substract two times and getting an error. In below total error is coming up

```
if result[0]['outTime'] != None:
type = "bothPunchDone"
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
total= datetime.strptime(result[0]['outTime'], FMT) - datetime.strptime(result[0]['inTime'], FMT)
```

I tried but not able to solve the issue.

Comment: result[0]['outTime'] is this string or int check then if its int you can convert it to sting using str(result[0]['outTime'])

Comment: my current time is in formatt = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

Comment: try printing type(result[0]['outTime'] ) and type(result[0]['inTime']) and see

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

result = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

if result != None:
    type = "bothPunchDone"
    
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
total= datetime.strptime(result, FMT) - datetime.strptime(result, FMT)

print(total)
```

is working for me. Try to check the type of `result[0]['outTime']`

Comment: i have tried printing and that is int .total= datetime.strptime(result[0]['outTime'], FMT) - datetime.strptime(result[0]['inTime'], FMT) now how to convert it into string

Comment: I think your 'outTime' might not in the format of "%H:%M:%S". You should change like that. please show example of your 'outTime' data. Is it in seconds?

Comment: if result[0]['outTime'] != None:       
            
                typeIn = "bothPunchDone"
                result[0]['outTime']=str(result[0]['outTime'])
                result[0]['inTime']=str(result[0]['inTime'])
                               
                total= datetime.strptime(result[0]['outTime'],FMT) - datetime.strptime(result[0]['inTime'],FMT)
                totalTime= total-getBreaksTotalTime(result[0]['id'],FMT) i did this and converted to str . now error shows up time data '2' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' . also i have checked my out time is in format of 12:25:41

Comment: if result[0]['outTime'] is int, it cannot be the format of 12:25:41. You should double check it. Just do `result[0]['outTime']` just in front of the error.